# using like in join with code igniter active records

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I am having issues with a particular like in my active records query.

When I use `join('users parent', 'child.treePath LIKE CONCAT(parent.treePath,"%")')`
Code igniter spits out `JOIN 'users' parent ON 'child'.'treePath' 'LIKE' CONCAT(parent.treePath,"%")` (note that I have replaced all back ticks (`` ` ``) with (`'`) due to markdown :/)

So, the issue is that code igniter is wrapping LIKE in (`` ` ``).

How can I tell it to **not** attempt to format this block?

---

Complete query:

```
$this->db->select('child.uuid')
         ->from('users child')
         ->join('users parent', 'child.treePath LIKE CONCAT(parent.treePath,"%")')
         ->where('parent.uuid', $uuid)
         ->where("LENGTH(REPLACE(child.treePath, parent.treePath, '')) - LENGTH(REPLACE(REPLACE(child.treePath, parent.treePath, ''), '/', '')) <= ",  $levels, 'false')
         ->where("LENGTH(REPLACE(child.treePath, parent.treePath, '')) - LENGTH(REPLACE(REPLACE(child.treePath, parent.treePath, ''), '/', '')) > ",  0, 'false')
         ->group_by('child.treeId');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are chaining all these functions together in a single call, you might as well just use

```
$this->db->query("Write all your specific SQL here");
```

Not seeing the benefit of wrestling with Codeigniter's query builder in your case.

Comment: just remember when you not using CI's active record you should mysql_real_escape_string() any user input