# LEFT JOIN not getting desired result

Tags: mysql

So I have 2 tables, first table is clock_in_out I am selecting loggedin and loggedout dates from this table. The second table breaks I am selecting in and out fields. There can be fiedls in clock_in_out that dont match the breaks table... I am joining them on user_id.

The problem is I only get results when breaks has a matching field, I thought left join would get all data from the left table and use fake rows with NULL for non matched data.

Below is my query:

```
SELECT `clock_in_out`.`loggedin`, `clock_in_out`.`loggedout`, `breaks`.`in`, 
      `breaks`.`out` FROM (`clock_in_out`) 
LEFT JOIN `breaks` ON `clock_in_out`.`user_id` = `breaks`.`user_id`      
WHERE 
      `clock_in_out`.`user_id` = 47 
      AND `breaks`.`user_id` = 47 
      AND `clock_in_out`.`loggedin` LIKE "%2015-03-13%" 
      AND `clock_in_out`.`loggedout` LIKE "%2015-03-13%" 
      AND `breaks`.`in` LIKE "%2015-03-13%"
      AND `breaks`.`out` LIKE "%2015-03-13%"
```

I am using CodeIgniter's prepared statements for queries and I am unsure how to get the desired result using them: Here is what I have:

```
    $this->db->select('clock_in_out.loggedin, clock_in_out.loggedout, breaks.in, breaks.out');
    $this->db->from('clock_in_out');

    $this->db->join('breaks','clock_in_out.user_id = breaks.user_id', 'LEFT');

    $this->db->like('breaks.in', $today);
    $this->db->like('breaks.out', $today);
    $this->db->where('clock_in_out.user_id = '.$user_id);
    $this->db->like('clock_in_out.loggedin', $today);
    $this->db->like('clock_in_out.loggedout', $today);

    $q = $this->db->get();
```

This produces:

```
SELECT `clock_in_out`.`loggedin`, `clock_in_out`.`loggedout`, `breaks`.`in`, `breaks`.`out` FROM (`clock_in_out`)
LEFT JOIN `breaks` ON `clock_in_out`.`user_id` = `breaks`.`user_id`
WHERE `clock_in_out`.`user_id` = 47
AND `breaks`.`in` LIKE '%2015-03-13%'
AND `breaks`.`out` LIKE '%2015-03-13%'
AND `clock_in_out`.`loggedin` LIKE '%2015-03-13%' AND `clock_in_out`.`loggedout` LIKE '%2015-03-13%'
```

Query produced from CI answer edits:

```
SELECT `clock_in_out`.`loggedin`, `clock_in_out`.`loggedout`, `breaks`.`in`, `breaks`.`out` FROM (`clock_in_out`)
LEFT JOIN `breaks` ON `clock_in_out`.`user_id` = `breaks`.`user_id`
WHERE `clock_in_out`.`user_id` = 47 
AND `clock_in_out`.`loggedin` LIKE '%2015-03-13%' 
AND `clock_in_out`.`loggedout` LIKE '%2015-03-13%'
```

Regards

Comment: Please, avoid writing code in a long horizontal line - it's very hard to comprehend, and we have to scroll a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get only the matching fields from breaks table because you are using it inside `WHERE`. Try this:

```
SELECT `clock_in_out`.`loggedin`, `clock_in_out`.`loggedout`, `breaks`.`in`, 
      `breaks`.`out` FROM (`clock_in_out`) 
LEFT JOIN `breaks` ON 
      `clock_in_out`.`user_id` = `breaks`.`user_id`    
      AND `breaks`.`in` LIKE "%2015-03-13%"
      AND `breaks`.`out` LIKE "%2015-03-13%"
WHERE 
      `clock_in_out`.`user_id` = 47 
      AND `clock_in_out`.`loggedin` LIKE "%2015-03-13%" 
      AND `clock_in_out`.`loggedout` LIKE "%2015-03-13%"
```

### Update for CodeIgniter

Make sure, that `$today` is properly escaped to avoid SQL injection.

```
    $this->db->select('clock_in_out.loggedin, 
                       clock_in_out.loggedout,
                       breaks.in, 
                       breaks.out');
    $this->db->from('clock_in_out');

    $this->db->join('breaks','clock_in_out.user_id = breaks.user_id 
                AND `breaks`.`in` LIKE "%'.$today.'%" 
                AND `breaks`.`out` LIKE "%'.$today.'%"', 'LEFT');

    $this->db->where('clock_in_out.user_id = '.$user_id);
    $this->db->like('clock_in_out.loggedin', $today);
    $this->db->like('clock_in_out.loggedout', $today);

    $q = $this->db->get()
```

Comment: I get this but I am using CodeIgniter so I have to use the prepared statements, I have edited my question

Comment: @Richard I wrote an update for you. You'll have to chain the conditions inside `join` call.

Comment: this basically acts like a select * from table (event dates from yesterday are appearing) when I have results in the breaks table being returned.. When I don't it returns nothing.. I have edited my originalpost to show the query produced from this.

Comment: @Richard What if you put the AND conditions in one line inside join? Very strange, that it doesn't produce a join with multiple conditions. Try to experiment. If it won't work, you'll need to prepare a SELECT statement manually and run it through `query` function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351781/using-like-in-join-with-code-igniter-active-records

Answer (score 2):

The `LEFT JOIN` does what you say (selects all the rows from the left table, pairs them with rows full of `NULL`s when there is no match on the right table).

But then the `WHERE` conditions come and filter the joined set. And your `WHERE` conditions on fields of the right-side table (`breaks`) filter out the rows having `NULL` values on those fields.

Comment: I think the query from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29029365/4265352) provided by @user4025 is the best way to get the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove condition for `breaks`.`user_id` = 47

```
SELECT 
`clock_in_out`.`loggedin`,
`clock_in_out`.`loggedout`, 
`breaks`.`in`, 
`breaks`.`out` 
FROM (`clock_in_out`) 
LEFT JOIN `breaks` ON `clock_in_out`.`user_id` = `breaks`.`user_id`
WHERE 
`clock_in_out`.`user_id` = 47 
AND `clock_in_out`.`loggedin` LIKE "%2015-03-13%" 
AND `clock_in_out`.`loggedout` LIKE "%2015-03-13%" 
AND (`breaks`.`in` LIKE "%2015-03-13%"  or `breaks`.`in` is null )
AND (`breaks`.`out` LIKE "%2015-03-13%" or `breaks`.`out` is null)
```